# How to read updating text file with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, text, output

I have one application(I dont have source code), which prints its output into console. I am writing its output to file like;

```
./otherApp > out.txt
```

And with c++ qt programming, I am writing an application which should also read its output **simultaneously**. However my code is only reading out.txt file which is created. I mean while otherApp is continue to write output, if my project finished reading, it is not reading the rest of output file.

Here is usual method with QTextStream about reading output.

```
QString fileName = "/.1/Work/appOutput/out1";

QFile inputFile(fileName);
if(inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QTextStream in(&inputFile);
    while(!in.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = in.readLine();

        qDebug() << line;
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

My question is how I can read out text file until I close otherApp or after it does not write anything inside?

**EDIT:**

thanks to @Bowdzone I changed my code and it is working. Here is my code.

```
    QString program = "/.1/Work/otherApp";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "-x" <<  "1002";

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
    myProcess->start(program, arguments);

    QString strOut = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput();

    qDebug() << QTime::currentTime().toString() << strOut;

    myProcess->waitForFinished();
```

However qDebug() does not show output of otherApp as soon as there is log in  application. Looks like `myProcess->waitForFinished()` should not be placed because as soon as application start it create another process and I cannot see logs in Qt Project. Could you please help me how I can see logs in same time?

Comment: You could use [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) to start the other app from within your app and use its methods to read the output directly and not having to use a text file.

Comment: @Bowdzone could you give me small sample to be more clear?

Comment: It is all in the documentation. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#details) it shows you how to use `QProcess` to start an external program. Then it emits the [`readyReadStandardOutput()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput) signal whenever the program wrote something to stdout which you can read using [`readAllStandardOutput()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readAllStandardOutput)

Comment: @Bowdzone could you please see my latest edit

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this is instead of reading the standard output from the `QProcess` as mentioned in the comments would be to use [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html) and read the file whenever `QFileSystemWatcher::fileChanged` signal is emitted. However then you would need to either remember where you stopped reading or discard the contents that you have already read in so if it is possible a switch to the standard output would be much more convenient.

Comment: Yes, than I need to know how I will remember my last line? Because there is no descriptive things to remember.

Comment: @goGud this is just a suggestion and you will have to test it yourself but what you cod do is remember the `QTextStream::pos()` value and then when reopening the file use `QTextStream::seek()` to position the stream at the position where  you stopped. However, again, if there are no limitations why you can't use standard output use that. If not and file is the only way than try this combo.

Comment: Could you please check my latest edit. Maybe after that time your solution could solve my problem.